# Python split method with lower

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I am trying understand why the solution to the below exercise requires the presence of `[0]` in `name.split()[0].lower()`:

> Use a list comprehension to create a new list `first_names` containing
>   just the first names in `names` in lowercase.
>
> ```
> names = ["Rick Sanchez", "Morty Smith", "Summer Smith", "Jerry Smith", "Beth Smith"]
>
> first_names = [name.split()[0].lower() for name in names] # write your list comprehension here
> print(first_names)
> ```

Comment: `[0]` will pick the first element after splitting the string. Read more about `spilt` method.

Comment: Example: `name = "Rick Sanchez" -> name.split() equals ["Rick", "Sanchez"]. So,, name.split()[0] -> "Rick"`

Comment: Calling `split()` on a string of space-separated words will split it into a list of words (e.g. `['Rick', 'Sanchez']`). Calling `[0]` on that list will return the first item in the list (e.g. `'Rick'`). Calling `lower` on that string will make it lower case (e.g. `'rick'`). In your example that’s all chained together inside your list comprehension, creating a list of lowercase first names.

Answer (score 1):

`split()` returns a list of all words divided by a space, meaning that it returns

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"] = "foo bar baz".split()
```

You only have two words, so it returns

```
["Rick", "Sanchez"] = "Rick Sanchez".split()
```

The `[0]` gives you the first value in the returned list.

See the documentation for more information.
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 0):

`name.split()` takes the name "Rick Sanchez" and creates a list of ['Rick', 'Sanchez'].

`name[0] == 'Rick'`

`name[1] == 'Sanchez'`

That is why [0] is necessary to specify that you want only the first name ('Rick')